# ElasticSearch: No filter registered for [match]]

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do this query to my ElasticSearch Server.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "name" : "network"
        }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "departments" : { 
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "department_name"
            } 
        }
    },

    "filter" : {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                { "match" : {"department_name" : "book"}},
                { "match" : {"department_name" : "electronics"}}]            
        }   
    }
}
```

Basically, I wish to retrieve all the products that match "network" in its name, but filtering only to those which `department_name` matches either `book` or `electronics`. When I perform this query, I receive this error message.

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/products/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "name" : "network"
        }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "departments" : { 
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "department_name"
            } 
        }
    },

    "filter" : {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                { "match" : {"department_name" : "book"}},
                { "match" : {"department_name" : "electronics"}}]            
        }   
    }
}
'

{
  "error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[EaNRci0OSIqpA2EAPwAA6w][products][4]: SearchParseException[[products][4]: query[name:network],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n    \"query\" : {\n        \"match\" : {\n            \"name\" : \"network\"\n        }\n    },\n    \"facets\" : {\n        \"departments\" : { \n            \"terms\" : {\n                \"field\" : \"department_name\"\n            } \n        }\n    },\n\n    \"filter\" : {\n        \"bool\": {\n            \"should\": [\n                { \"match\" : {\"department_name\" : \"book\"}},\n                { \"match\" : {\"department_name\" : \"electronics\"}}]            \n        }   \n    }\n}\n]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[products] No filter registered for [match]]; }{[EaNRci0OSIqpA2EAPwAA6w][products][0]: SearchParseException[[products][0]: query[name:network],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n    \"query\" : {\n        \"match\" : {\n            \"name\" : \"network\"\n        }\n    },\n    \"facets\" : {\n        \"departments\" : { \n            \"terms\" : {\n                \"field\" : \"department_name\"\n            } \n        }\n    },\n\n    \"filter\" : {\n        \"bool\": {\n            \"should\": [\n                { \"match\" : {\"department_name\" : \"book\"}},\n                { \"match\" : {\"department_name\" : \"electronics\"}}]            \n        }   \n    }\n}\n]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[products] No filter registered for [match]]; }{[EaNRci0OSIqpA2EAPwAA6w][products][1]: SearchParseException[[products][1]: query[name:network],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n    \"query\" : {\n        \"match\" : {\n            \"name\" : \"network\"\n        }\n    },\n    \"facets\" : {\n        \"departments\" : { \n            \"terms\" : {\n                \"field\" : \"department_name\"\n            } \n        }\n    },\n\n    \"filter\" : {\n        \"bool\": {\n            \"should\": [\n                { \"match\" : {\"department_name\" : \"book\"}},\n                { \"match\" : {\"department_name\" : \"electronics\"}}]            \n        }   \n    }\n}\n]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[products] No filter registered for [match]]; }{[EaNRci0OSIqpA2EAPwAA6w][products][2]: SearchParseException[[products][2]: query[name:network],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n    \"query\" : {\n        \"match\" : {\n            \"name\" : \"network\"\n        }\n    },\n    \"facets\" : {\n        \"departments\" : { \n            \"terms\" : {\n                \"field\" : \"department_name\"\n            } \n        }\n    },\n\n    \"filter\" : {\n        \"bool\": {\n            \"should\": [\n                { \"match\" : {\"department_name\" : \"book\"}},\n                { \"match\" : {\"department_name\" : \"electronics\"}}]            \n        }   \n    }\n}\n]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[products] No filter registered for [match]]; }{[EaNRci0OSIqpA2EAPwAA6w][products][3]: SearchParseException[[products][3]: query[name:network],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n    \"query\" : {\n        \"match\" : {\n            \"name\" : \"network\"\n        }\n    },\n    \"facets\" : {\n        \"departments\" : { \n            \"terms\" : {\n                \"field\" : \"department_name\"\n            } \n        }\n    },\n\n    \"filter\" : {\n        \"bool\": {\n            \"should\": [\n                { \"match\" : {\"department_name\" : \"book\"}},\n                { \"match\" : {\"department_name\" : \"electronics\"}}]            \n        }   \n    }\n}\n]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[products] No filter registered for [match]]; }]",
  "status" : 400
}
```

I suppose the key here is `QueryParsingException[[products] No filter registered for [match]]`, but cannot understand what's wrong here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`match` is a query, not a filter.

You probably want the `term`-filter in this case.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer. I'm really new with ElasticSearch. An extra question: can I do analyzed search with any filter? Just like `match` do.

Comment: Hi. The term filters do not do any text analysis. You can turn a query into a filter using the [query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html)-filter. (That's a filter named "query" that wraps a query. Naming is difficult :-)

Comment: I think ElasticSearch lack some good books and references... Thanks for the explanation! I haven't seen the difference up to now.

Comment: I think you can also just wrap your match in a query {} object

Comment: Eric Uldall is correct, wrapping the `match` in `query` works.

Answer (score 9):

## Elasticsearch Advanced Filtering

#### Here's a way you can use match inside of a bool:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": { //THIS IS THE MAIN SEARCH BLOCK FOR ALL RESULTS
        "match": { 
          "title": { 
            "query": "[MAIN_SEARCH_TERM]", 
            "minimum_should_match": "75%"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": { //THIS FILTERS BY DATES GRATER THAN [SOME_DATE]
                "date": {
                  "gte":"[SOME DATE]"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "geo_distance": { //THIS FILTERS BY GEO POINTS WITHIN [DISTANCE] of [LATITUDE], [LONGITUDE]
                "distance": "[DISTANCE](mi, km)",
                "location": {
                  "lat":"[LATITUDE]",
                  "lon":"[LONGITUDE]"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "query": { //THIS FILTERS BY ANOTHER [MATCH_TERM] AND ADDS BOOST TO THAT TERM, YOU CAN USE MULTIPLE OF THESE WITH DIFFERENT [BOOST_INT]
                "match": { 
                  "[PROPERTY]": {
                    "query": "[MATCH_TERM]",
                    "boost": [BOOST_INT]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reference Link: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-time-boosting.html

Before using geo_point matching and date range filtering, make sure you understand _mapping:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this who migrated up major version(s) to elastic search 5, this filtered query is now depreciated and you should use a bool query instead. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/no-query-registered-for-filter/49602