# Elastic search query with filter - Elastic search 1.7

Tags: elasticsearch

Posting this to elastic search throws exception 
org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [myapp] No filter registered for [match]

```
 http://localhost:9200/  
      GET myapp/_search/
    {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "userName": "Micky"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match": {
                    "Age": 21
                  }
                }
              ],
              "should": [],
              "must_not": []
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "from": 0,
      "size": 20
    }
```

why this query is wrong (technical detail)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch: No filter registered for \[match\]\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116803/elasticsearch-no-filter-registered-for-match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no filter named `match`, you can either use `term` instead

```
POST myapp/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "userName": "Micky"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "Age": 21
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}
```

or use a `constant_score` query instead of `filtered` since you have no filters.

```
POST myapp/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "userName": "Micky"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "Age": 21
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}
```

Comment: exception "error": "org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [myapp] request does not support [from]"

Comment: Bad copy/paste? Works fine for me.

Comment: Bad paste!! , Thanks, the second one works fine for me, first one doesn't return any data

Comment: For the first one, you probably need to lowercase `Micky` to `micky` and it will work, because term filters are not analyzed.

Comment: And you're certain you have at least one matching document?

Comment: Is `Micky` the full username or just a token thereof?

Comment: it is the full name, name can be up to 36 characters and contain '-' or '_'

Comment: Do you mind sharing a sample document containing `Micky`?