# How can I create a nested AND+OR query in Elasticsearch involving analyzed and not-analyzed fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have three fields, A,B and C. C is an analyzed field storing emails and I need a full match.

In SQL terms, I need to write a query like,

```
select * from table where A = '123' OR (B = '456' AND A = '' ) OR ( C = 'abc@xyz.com' AND A = '' AND B = '');
```

I wrote the query below at my first attempt, but I get a Parse exception error.

```
No filter registered for [match]];
```

As soon as I remove the block with the match query, I start getting results which makes me assume I cannot write the query this way.

Do let me know if you have any suggestions.

```
{   "size": 25,   "query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter":{
            "or":[
                {"term": {"A":  "123"}},
                {
                    "and":[
                        {"term": {"B":  "456"}},
                        {"term": {"A":  ""}}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "and":[
                        {
                            "match":{
                                "C":{
                                    "query": "abc@xyz.com",
                                    "operator": "AND"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {"term": {"A":  ""}},
                        {"term": {"B":  ""}}
                    ]   
                }
            ]
        }
    }   } }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch: No filter registered for \[match\]\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116803/elasticsearch-no-filter-registered-for-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this one https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html
It should help you.

SQL query:

```
SELECT document
FROM   products
WHERE  productID = "KDKE-B-9947-#kL5"
OR (productID = "JODL-X-1937-#pV7" AND price = 30 )
```

ES query:

```
{
  "query" : {
  "constant_score" : {
     "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [
            { "term" : {"productID" : "KDKE-B-9947-#kL5"}}, 
            { "bool" : { 
              "must" : [
                { "term" : {"productID" : "JODL-X-1937-#pV7"}}, 
                { "term" : {"price" : 30}} 
              ]
            }
           }
          ]
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```