# using match_phrase twice on ES query filter? No filter registered for [match_phrase]

Tags: elasticsearch, jbuilder

I have been trying to fetch a document using multiple filters.

Im currently using ES 1.7 Is it possible to use `match_phrase` twice on a filter?

example: people document
`q=aaron&address=scarborough` - searching a person by name and address, works fine.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "name": "aaron"
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "addresses",
          "query": {
            "match_phrase": {
              "address": "scarborough"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

`q=aaron&phone=813-689-6889` - searching a person by name and phone number works fine as well.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "name": "aaron"
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query": {
          "match_phrase": {
            "phone": "813-689-6889"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

However, When I try to use both filters, address and phone I get a `No filter registered for [match_phrase]` error

for example: `q=aaron&address=scarborough&phone=813-689-6889`

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "name": "aaron"
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "addresses",
          "query": {
            "match_phrase": {
              "address": "scarborough"
            }
          }
        },
        "query": {
          "match_phrase": {
            "phone": "813-689-6889"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

the error, when using `address` and `phone` filters together:

```
nested: QueryParsingException[[pl_people] No filter registered for [match_phrase]]; }]","status":400}):
```

index mapping (person) as requested:

```
{
  "pl_people": {
    "mappings": {
      "person": {
        "properties": {
          "ac_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete"
          },
          "date_of_birth": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "email": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "first_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "na_first_name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "last_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "na_last_name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "middle_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "na_middle_name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "na_name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "ngram_name": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "my_start"
              },
              "ns_name": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "no_stopwords"
              }
            }
          },
          "phone": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "time": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "updated_at": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use term-filter, instead of match_phrase as a filter.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116803/elasticsearch-no-filter-registered-for-match).

Comment: when I replace `match_phrase`, with `term`, I get no documents back, when using the whole phone number: `&phone=813-689-6889`, however if I just put the initial part of the phone number, (everything before the first hyphen) it works.
ex: `&phone=813`
Do you know why is that?

Comment: Can you please put here the mapping of your index?

Comment: I think you'd better map the phone field as keyword, if you want exact match of it. 
Just as: 
PUT my_index 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "tags": {
        "type":  "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)

Comment: thanks so much for your time @Keiko Barbosa, just updated the question with the index mapping

Comment: keyword should be ideal for a phone field, but my dataset, in regards to phone number has many different phone formats, would that still work?

Comment: @queroga_vqz, no matter what kind of phone number format there is, if you set the field as a keyword, Elastic will look up for EXACT match. You also can set the field as both keyword and text type, and differenciate the use according to what you want.

Comment: tried it. unfortunately, keyword type, is not available on my ES version (1.7), is only available after version 5.x